# jQuery $each fadeIn fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

Everything works fine except one thing, I'd like it so when you have the `.show` class already visible, it will fade again when you click on another of the `#c-` divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/7KdR6/1/

```
$('[id^="c-"]').each(function(i){
    $this = $(this);
    $(this).text(i);
    $(this).on('click',function(){
        $('.show').fadeIn().text(i);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
})
$(document).on('click', function(){
     $('.show').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that you are not stopping the propagation because `event` is not being defined. You'll have to use the parameter for the `click` handler. **Edit:** Actually, it looks like `event` is automatically passed - I did not realize this before now. However, I still think it best to put the event object as the parameter if you are going to use it - jQuery does this in their examples and it makes it more obvious.

I also notice you are caching `this` but then not using that cached var. This means that every time you write `$(this)`, it will have to rewrap that jquery object.

Then you can have a fadeOut and use the fadeIn as a callback for the fadeOut. This way if the `.show` element is already shown, it will fadeOut first. I'd write it like this:

```
$('[id^="c-"]').each(function (i) {
    $this = $(this);
    $this.text(i);
    $this.on('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $show = $(".show");
        $show.fadeOut(function () {
            $show.fadeIn().text(i);
        });
    });
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mKY6Z/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to hide the element before using fadeIn on a visible element

```
$('[id^="c-"]').each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.text(i);
    $this.on('click', function () {
        $('.show').hide().fadeIn().text(i);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mKY6Z/)

Answer (score 2):

Try calling [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) before calling `.fadeIn()`.

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EAh9s/)**